# Animate the rotation of the Marker in google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-animation

i am using google maps v2.
i have a marker on map, this marker changes rotation every while.
I want to animate the rotation of my maker to rotate smoothly.
Can anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static public void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation, GoogleMap map) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
    final long duration = 1555;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

            float rot = t * toRotation + (1 -t) * startRotation;

            marker.setRotation(-rot > 180 ? rot/2 : rot);
            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

i have managed to do it :)

Comment: How did you calculate what the toRotation should be?

Comment: That actually doesn't work well when passing moving between left and right sides of the northern hemisphere - like: 350deg -> 10deg - it's not moving clockwise but anticlockwise or in opposite 10deg -> 350deg - it's not moving anticlockwise but clockwise which is wrong. It should take the shorter turn.

Comment: Please mention how to get toRotation

Comment: @user007 did you fix it?

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- well, yeah, see my answer above @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967821/animate-the-rotation-of-the-marker-in-google-map-v2/34219408#34219408 I use that implementation in my app.

Answer (score 9):

That's mine implementation of smooth marker movement with maker image rotation (when it's set to FLAT [important]). The marker is moved to the requested location smoothly plus it's rotated to the requested degree with a proper direction. For example, when moving from 5deg to 355deg it moves anticlockwise, when 355deg to 5deg it moves clockwise.

```
public void animateMarker(final Location location)
{
    if (myMarkerLOC != null) {
        final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        final LatLng startPosition = myMarkerLOC.getPosition();
        final float startRotation = myMarkerLOC.getRotation();
        final float angle = 180 - Math.abs(Math.abs(startRotation - location.getBearing()) - 180);
        final float right = WhichWayToTurn(startRotation, location.getBearing());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
            {
                try {
                    if (myMarkerLOC == null) // oops... destroying map during animation...
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                    LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, PositionUtil.toLatLng(location));
                    float rotation = startRotation + right * v * angle;
                    myMarkerLOC.setRotation((float) rotation);
                    myMarkerLOC.setPosition(newPosition);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // I don't care atm..
                }
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.setFloatValues(0, 1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(300);
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}
private float WhichWayToTurn(float currentDirection, float targetDirection)
{
    float diff = targetDirection - currentDirection;
    if (Math.abs(diff) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(diff > 180)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
public interface LatLngInterpolator 
{
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

    public class Linear implements LatLngInterpolator 
    {
        @Override
        public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) 
        {
            double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
            double lng = (b.longitude - a.longitude) * fraction + a.longitude;
            return new LatLng(lat, lng);
        }
    }
    public class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolator 
    {
        @Override
        public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
            double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
            double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
            // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
            if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
            }
            double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
            return new LatLng(lat, lng);
        }
    }
}
```

Missing implementation of "toLatLong" method:

```
 public static LatLng toLatLng(final Location location)
 {
    return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
 }
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: What is PositionUtil?

Comment: I think the PositionUtil is a custom class that has a method to convert Location object to LatLng object. Please correct me if I am wrong. This simply draws multiple markers instead of animating the marker. Can you explain to why is this happening?

Comment: @The_Martian:  PositionUtil is my util class for various calculcations. In this case "PositionUtil.toLatLng" is a static method that converts location to LatLong. So yes, you're right :)

Comment: i am unable to make my marker rotate with the direction

Comment: what do you mean? If the Location contains proper Bearing it will just rotate to that direction.

Comment: this sounds to be more simple, I like it

Answer (score 9):

```
boolean isRotating = false;
public void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation) {
    if(!isRotating) {
        isRotating = true;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
        final long duration = 1000;
        float deltaRotation = Math.abs(toRotation - startRotation) % 360;
        final float rotation = (deltaRotation > 180 ? 360 - deltaRotation : deltaRotation) *
                ((toRotation - startRotation >= 0 && toRotation - startRotation <= 180) || (toRotation - startRotation <= -180 && toRotation - startRotation >= -360) ? 1 : -1);

        final LinearInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
                marker.setRotation((startRotation + t * rotation) % 360);
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    isRotating = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is how I rotate the marker, I don't know this is the best code or not.
But I think it will prevent wrong rotation. EDIT: Add var isRotating (Thanks @Trần Văn Huy)

Update Explanation:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was looking for that angle calculation!

Comment: @ChintanShah Look like this angle calculation provide `rotation` with the wrong value (sign). For example -41 instead 41 or 54.5 instead -54.5. Did you fix it?

Comment: ***Important note*** `toRotation` should be between -180 and 180. For example you can use `(float)SphericalUtil.computeHeading(startPosition, endPosition)` this method return value within the range [-180,180)
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeHeading-LatLng-LatLng-

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- I have not checked for the values you have provided but it was working fine for me when I implemented in my project one year ago.

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- sry bro, I assume that you misinterpret about my "sign", i have update my answer with detail explanation. Thank you

Comment: @BhagaskaraLiancer try this kml file. Init rotation = 0;
https://justpaste.it/6jsrm
(first value - longitude)

Answer (score 2):

With @Bhagaskara Liancer answer.Add var isMarkerRotating with help marker rotate smoothly.

```
private boolean isMarkerRotating = false;
public void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation) {
    if(!isMarkerRotating){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
        final long duration = 1000;
        float deltaRotation = Math.abs(toRotation - startRotation) % 360;
        final float rotation = (deltaRotation > 180 ? 360 - deltaRotation : deltaRotation) * ((toRotation - startRotation >= 0 && toRotation - startRotation <= 180)
                || (toRotation - startRotation <=-180 && toRotation- startRotation>= -360) ? 1 : -1);

        final LinearInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isMarkerRotating = true;
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
                marker.setRotation((startRotation + t* rotation)%360);
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                }else {
                    isMarkerRotating = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example
You can use the following MarkerAnimation class for animating marker with rotation.

```
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

import com.gogrocerycart.settings.Constants;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

/**
 * Created by Vinil Chandran on 7/6/18.
 */

public class MarkerAnimation {
    private static Location fromPosition;
    private static float angle = 0;
    public static void move(GoogleMap mMap, final Marker marker, final Location toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition != null && marker != null && toPosition != null) {
            final Handler handlerRotation = new Handler();
            final long startAngle = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
            final long durationRotation = 300;
            final Interpolator interpolatorRotation = new LinearInterpolator();
            float bearing = fromPosition.bearingTo(toPosition);
            Print.e("Bearing:" + bearing);
            angle = bearing<0?(360+bearing):bearing;
            angle = angle%360f;
            Print.e("Angle:" + angle);
            handlerRotation.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startAngle;
                    float t = interpolatorRotation.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / durationRotation);
                    float rot = t * angle + (1 - t) * startRotation;
                    float mAngle = -rot > 180 ? rot / 2 : rot;
                    marker.setRotation(mAngle);

                    if (t < 1.0) {
                        handlerRotation.postDelayed(this, 16);
                    } else {
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                        Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();
                        Point startPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
                        final LatLng startLatLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
                        final long duration = Constants.LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL;
                        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                                        / duration);
                                double lng = t * toPosition.getLongitude() + (1 - t)
                                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                                double lat = t * toPosition.getLatitude() + (1 - t)
                                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                                if (t < 1.0) {
                                    // Post again 16ms later.
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        fromPosition = toPosition;
    }
}
```

Just call the following code for moving the marker when the location is changed.

```
if (carMarker != null) {
      MarkerAnimation.move(mMap,carMarker, location);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, in my case I used `ValueAnimator`

```
    static public void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(marker.getRotation(), toRotation);
    animator.setDuration(duration);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float rotate = Float.parseFloat(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
            marker.setRotation(rotate);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Alexandr Kolesnik seems to be the most simple.
Here's a Kotlin extension version of it.

You can pass in an interpolator to avoid a little thrash.

```
fun Marker.animateRotation(toRotation: Float, interpolator: TimeInterpolator? = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()) {
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(rotation, toRotation)
    animator.duration = 500
    animator.interpolator = interpolator
    animator.addUpdateListener {
        rotation = it.animatedValue as? Float ?: return@addUpdateListener
    }

    animator.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [MarkerOption rotation method](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#rotation(float))

```
 public MarkerOptions rotation (float rotation)
```

> Sets the rotation of the marker in degrees clockwise about the
>   marker's anchor point. The axis of rotation is perpendicular to the
>   marker. A rotation of 0 corresponds to the default position of the
>   marker. When the marker is flat on the map, the default position is
>   North aligned and the rotation is such that the marker always remains
>   flat on the map. When the marker is a billboard, the default position
>   is pointing up and the rotation is such that the marker is always
>   facing the camera. The default value is 0.
>
> Returns the object for which the method was called, with the new
>   rotation set.