# Marker drawn multiple times instead of animating on Map V2

Tags: android, android-animation, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to animate a car marker along the street when I move. But the marker is drawn multiple times instead of moving on the street. I have tried multiple codes including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967821/animate-the-rotation-of-the-marker-in-google-map-v2?rq=1) but the same result every time. Can someone point me what is wrong?

This is another one that isn't working for me.

```
public void animateMarker(GoogleMap myMap, final Marker marker, final ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = myMap.getProjection();
        final long duration = 30000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                if (i < directionPoint.size())
                    marker.setPosition(directionPoint.get(i));
                i++;

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (marker.isVisible()) {
                        marker.remove();
                    } else {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

before calling
        marker.setPosition(directionPoint.get(i));

remove the marker and then call it

Comment: That solution throws npe on marker.setPosition line because marker is null. I did if (marker != null)marker.remove(); But I don't understand what you meant by "then call it".

Answer (score 0):

before set marker clear the map and reset marker its work for you

```
if (mMap != null) {
    mMap.clear();
}
```

Comment: I tried it right before I call marker.setPosition, but it didn't work.